# Difference between a form post and jquery post

Tags: php, jquery, html, post

I need to know the exact difference between:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://mywebsite/signon.php">
<input name="harv_acc" value="940322903" type="hidden" />
<input name="harv_eml" value="a@b.com" type="hidden" />
<input type="submit" value="SignOn" />
```

and

```
var url = "https://mywebsite/signon.php";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    //dataType: 'html', -- this was something I tried later
    //data: "harv_acc=" + accountnumber + "&harv_eml=" + email , this is also what I tried last but below is what I tried first
    data: { harv_acc: account, harv_eml: email },
    success: function (data) {
        closePopup("div_PleaseWait");
        alert(data);
        //window.location = encodeURI('<%= Url.Action("DownloadDocument", "Documents") %>?DocumentID=' + documentID + '&DownloadType=' + downloadType + '&DownloadPath=' + data);
    }
});
```

When I post the latter I get a 200 but no response.  If I submit the first one I get the correct response.

Comment: How are you returning data back from the file. You need to echo the output in your php file to get the response in ajax.

Comment: They look darn similar to me. What is the correct response?

Comment: @Cptcecil Can you post your php code

Comment: I do not have access to the php code, I'm posting to another site.  I suppose I could ask them for it though.  That would be rather helpful.

Comment: @Cptcecil Security prevents cross domain ajax requests. Thats why you are getting no response

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the comments:

> I'm posting to another site

Aha! There's your issue. Browsers block AJAX to external websites for security reasons. Sorry, but you're not going to issue that request via an XHR request.

If the other website *wants* you to communicate with them, they could expose this part of the site via JSON-P, which works something like this:

1. My site adds `<script src="http://othersite.com/signon.js?username=foo&password=bar&callback=myCallback">` to the source code (yeah, it's messy to use GET for this, but JSON-P can't work any other way), and creates a function named `myCallback` to handle the response data.
2. The other site signs in, then returns something like `myCallback({success: false, errorMessage: "Incorrect password, try again!"})`
3. That script is run on my site, calls `myCallback`, and everything is happy.

JSON-P is a powerful protocol, but only works if the remote site agrees to it. Still, if they do, jQuery has a nice shortcut for it: just set `dataType: "jsonp"` and it will handle the whole callback thing for you.

But if you're not closely involved with this website, that's unlikely to happen, and you'll probably just be stuck with having to give up on this kind of cross-site interaction. Sorry, but this kind of cross-domain policy is critical to online security. (I don't want other sites issuing requests to `bankofamerica.com` on my behalf, kthx.)

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter passed to your `complete` function will be a `jqXHR` object, which is a wrapper around the browser's `XMLHttpRequest` object. A more convenient way to handle the response is to use the `done` method:

```
var url = "https://mywebsite/signon.php";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: "harv_acc=" + accountnumber + "&harv_eml=" + email
}).done(function(data) {
    closePopup("div_PleaseWait");
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: Well, this would be the problem without the cross-domain issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try sending ther data as a key:value object. This is an example from the jQuery docs

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Update: as user Matchu pointed out, this is not the problem, as the data will be converted into a query string anyway, as stated in the jQuery docs:

> "The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. "

So yeah, some rash answering on my part there. At least *I* learned something! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain ajax requests are not supported by browser. But there is another way to get around this.

You can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) for cross-domain requests. It is easy to use and allows you to request anything (as long as it is in JSON format) from any server/script that supports the callback. The good thing about JSONP is that it works in older browsers too.

The only serious limitation seems to be that it always uses the HTTP GET method

Can you please check with this too.

Answer (score -2):

when using POST method you should ,in your case, Post your data as JSON

```
var url = "https://mywebsite/signon.php";
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {
      harv_acc : accountnumber,
      harv_eml : email
    },
    success: function (data) {
        closePopup("div_PleaseWait");
        alert(data);
        //window.location = encodeURI('<%= Url.Action("DownloadDocument", "Documents") %>?DocumentID=' + documentID + '&DownloadType=' + downloadType + '&DownloadPath=' + data);
    }
});
```

NOTE : i used dataType : JSON

Comment: Similarly to the other answer: `dataType` does *not* refer to the type of `data`, but rather the type of data we expect in the *response*. While it may be a stupid naming decision by the jQuery team, [it's at least well-documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Additionally, `data` *can* be a query string—in fact, if we give it the data in object form, jQuery will convert it to the corresponding query string. Still, the original version in the question isn't properly `encodeURIComponent`'d, so this could actually fix something.

Comment: i said "you should " not you must !!